# Use javascript to generate a file to be downloaded. How to use the 'Save As' dialogue without HTTP headers?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this function to download a file:

```
function download(fileName, data) {
    fileName = fileName.replace(/\s+/gi, '_').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-.,_]/gi, '');
    let blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/plain'});
    if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    }else{
        let elem = window.document.createElement('a');
        elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        elem.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
        elem.click();
        document.body.removeChild(elem);
    }
}

// Example usage
$('button').on('click', function(){
    download("test.txt", "test");
});
```

It works perfectly fine. However, it seems to download the file directly into the Downloads folder.
How can I make it open a 'Save As' dialogue instead, so the user can choose his preferred download location?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kbwrcL14/

I've seen suggestions before about manipulating the header like settiing a `Content-Disposition` -- however is that possible when you generate a file on-the-fly? Afaik headers are what is sent before the HTTP body, but by the time the JS code is running, the entire HTTP request has already finished, and the file is generated by the client itself.

Is there a way to make this work without using http headers?

Comment: The download location is decided by the browser.  That is, you can't control whether or not a "Save As" dialogue appears because that's a client-side configuration options, if I'm right.

Comment: Actually the `Content-Disposition` header is not sent in the request header but the response header. Meaning that to use that trick you have to modify server code, not javascript running on the web page.